# Modular Class modulo p

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to calculate modular class modulo p , with p = 11?
I tried using Fermat's Little Theorem, but there's that 7

[image]

Comment: can you see that $\bar{6}*\bar{2}=\bar{1}$?

Comment: Yes, but how do i use this with 7?

Comment: $7*6^{-1}=7*2=3$, right?

Comment: Yes. And now i have to calculate inverse of 3? That will be the solution or there's one more step?

Comment: well, one has $3*4=1$